# Auto-correct spelling option not available

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I can't find the checkbox to activate the option "Allow ML to correct spelling" as described here: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent

I am in 'Agent Settings' -> 'ML Setting' tab as discribed in the linked document but there is just no option to activate "Allow ML to correct spelling". Please see screenshot.

Thanks
Felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my issue:

Spell Correction feature is currently not available in non-US CX regions. So I moved my DialogFlow agent from European region to US and now the option for auto-correct spelling is there. All working fine!